# Control of movement of 3D Avatar in Blender with python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Blender, but I need to control the movements of a 3d avatar in blender using python. The idea is to detect the movements of a person through a camera and play them in real time in the avatar through a graphic interface. For now I created the avatars and generated motion using blender but I need to control using python, an example of what I need implement is located at the following link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lbz-l3HlmKM

Comment: Controlling your Avatar's rig is simple (access `rig.pose.bones`, then `pbone.location` or `pbone.rotation`, use control bones, constraints and any other trick you want). The hard part is translating your motion data into the the commands to apply on the rig. No simple solution here, you need to write your algorithm according to your specific rig and specific data.

Comment: I am working on a similar project, did you find how to link python with the avatar?